# Data extensions and folders not visible in marketing cloud when I created them via SOAP api

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, soap-api

I tried to create the a data folder and data extension via soap api. After the response returns OK, I am still not able to view it in marketing cloud ui. Here is the request and response.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <fueloauth>{{access_token}}</fueloauth>
</Header>
<Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options/>
        <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="DataFolder">
            <CustomerKey>api_folder</CustomerKey>
            <ParentFolder>
                <ID>{{folder_id}}</ID>
            </ParentFolder>
            <Name>api_folder</Name>
            <Description>api_folder</Description>
            <ContentType>dataextension</ContentType>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
            <AllowChildren>true</AllowChildren>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</Body>
```

then i got the response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:9dabdf03-fd92-4243-85a1-845f68974c47</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:ceb0d6b0-0404-42df-94d3-d4b4b14d3c9b</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-c6f6793f-02df-4162-9f8e-dfab100ba803">
                <wsu:Created>2022-08-31T08:37:40Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-08-31T08:42:40Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Results>
                <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
                <StatusMessage>Folder created successfully.</StatusMessage>
                <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
                <NewID>{{new_id}}</NewID>
                <NewObjectID>{{ne_object_id}}</NewObjectID>
            </Results>
            <RequestID>{{request_i}}</RequestID>
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
        </CreateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

appreciate your help

Comment: If you make the call again, do you get an error because the folder already exists? Does the parent folder ID you're specifying exist and is visible in the UI? Is this a shared folder you're trying to create or one in the local child BU?

Comment: The typical error I run into with this is that I have created a token for another BU by mistake, and am looking in the wrong BU. You can always try to retrieve the Data extension through SOAP API to be sure. And if all else fails, you can also delete it via API and start over.

Comment: @JonasLamberty Thank you. It turns out I am in the wrong BU. Now I am able to perform operations using SOAP API and find the changes in DEs.

Comment: glad to hear I am not the only one.  :) I am gonna insert my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The typical error I run into with this is that I have created a token for another BU by mistake, and am looking in the wrong BU. You can always try to retrieve the Data extension through SOAP API to be sure. And if all else fails, you can also delete it via API and start over.